# How do I integrate $x\sin x\sin 2x$?

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus

How do I integrate $x\sin x\sin 2x$? What rules can I follow if I cannot use integration by parts?

Comment: You can use that $\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$, so simplifying that expression yields $2x\sin^2(x)\cos(x)$. You can differentiate $2x$ and integrate $\sin^2(x)\cos(x)$, so by parts can work nicely or the answer below works as well with integration by parts.

Comment: Why can't you use integration by parts? Are you not allowed to?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$\sin x\sin (2x)=\frac{1}{2}\cos(x-2x)-\frac{1}{2}\cos(x+2x)=\frac{1}{2}\cos(-x)-\frac{1}{2}\cos 3x$$

Comment: And then integrate by parts

Comment: I believe the $\sin(x)\sin(2x) = \frac{1}{2}\cos(-x) - \frac{1}{2}\cos(3x)$.

Comment: @MathNewbie Yes, it was a typo. I have corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$\displaystyle I = \int x\cdot \sin x\cdot \sin 2x dx =\int x\cdot \sin x\cdot 2\sin x\cos xdx= \int \underbrace{x}_{\bf{1^{st}}}\cdot \underbrace{\sin^2 x\cdot \cos dx}_{\bf{2^{nd}}}$$

Now Using Integration by parts, we get

$\displaystyle I = x\int \sin^2 x\cdot \cos xdx-\int \left[\frac{d}{dx}(x)\cdot \int \sin^2 x\cdot \cos xdx\right]dx$

So we get $$\displaystyle I = x\cdot \frac{\sin^3 x}{3}-\frac{1}{3}\int \sin^3 xdx$$

Now Using $$\displaystyle \bullet \sin (3x) = 3\sin x-4\sin^3 x\Rightarrow \left[\frac{3\sin x-\sin 3x}{4}\right]$$

So we get $$\displaystyle I =\frac{x\sin^3 x}{3}-\frac{1}{12}\int \left[3\sin x-\sin 3x\right]dx$$

So we get $$\displaystyle I =\frac{x\sin^3 x}{3}+\frac{3}{12}\cos x-\frac{\cos 3x}{36}+\mathcal{C}$$

Comment: Why can't we use integration by parts on just $x.sinx.sin2x$? And did you again used by parts on $sin^2x.cosx$?

Answer (score 0):

$x\sin x\sin2x$ is odd, so the integral will be even.
Try $Ax\cos x\sin2x+Bx\sin x\cos2x+C\cos x\cos2x+D\sin x\sin2x$.  Differentiate and solve for $A,B,C,D$